# Oracle Apex Chart Label color

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

I know this is a silly one but haven't been able to fix my chart.
I have a bar chart created showing the number of Reps per Location and I want to have my label in white. What I'm doing right now is to go to the X Axe, under the Title option I'm choosing ''white'' as the Font Color. But this doesn't have any effect (label is still black).
Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: my_image]

Edit --

Thank you for the help!
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, have no CSS no nothing but still it won't change the label color. Example below with dummy data on a blank new page:

X Axe:
[image: tick_color_x_axe]

[image: my_chart_dummy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The Apex Team has raised a bug ticket to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not *that* font color; scroll down to **Tick Label** and set its color:

[image]

Comment: Hi LittleFoot! you always help me out, appreciate it a lot!
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, it doesn't work :-/
Do you know why? (snaps on the -now edited- question)

Comment: I wouldn't know; as you can see, it works for me on apex.oracle.com

Comment: Thank you. It seems that using the following JS function would help:
function(options){
  options.xAxis.tickLabel.style = {"color": "#FFFFFF"}
  options.legend.textStyle = {"color": "#FFFFFF"}
  return options
}
But! It's not working for me (I'm sure it is because of me).
Does that one rings a bell perhaps? or maybe you know where I should use it/initiate it?
Thanks!

Comment: Update: The Apex Team has raised a bug to fix this behavior.